# Use response from a restful webservice endpoint call to be used later on in some other webservice endPoint call

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services

I want response from one webservice call to be used later on by some other webservice call. How do I implement the code flow for it. Do I have to maintain a session?
I am creating the restful webservices using Spring,java
If user 1 calls an endPoint /getUserRecord and 1 minute later calls /checkUserRecord which uses data from the first call, how to handle it since user 2 can call /getUserRecord before user 1 calls /checkUserRecord
I am using Spring java to create RESTFul webservices.

Thanks,
Arpit

Comment: don't make it stateful. Pass the id you got from the first call to the other one.

Comment: But that would require making another call to Database. What I had in mind was to retrieve userRecord in the first call and use that in the second call without making another call to Databse.. Any Suggestions on that?

Comment: in the second call, I believe you need to pass the whole userRecord to /checkUserRecord. No needs to retrieve from DB.

Comment: Then how do I retrieve the userRecord without making a Database call in the second webServiceCall?

Comment: you cache it or take the tradeoff for the good stateless design and ask the database again. If the user already has the data why would he do a request for the same? maybe your api design is not the best. You know if you have verbs like get or check in your endpoints something is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically you can pass UserRecord from get to check.

GET /userrecords/ --> return the one or more record

POST /checkUserRecord with the record as you want to check as request body.

But I strongly advise you **to not do this**. Data provided by client are unreliable and cannot be trust by your backend code. What if some javascript has altered the original data ? Besides, what if you have a list of data or heterogenous payload to pass back and forth, it would end up to a complete mess of payload exchanges from client and server.

So as Veselin Davidov said, you should probably stick with clean stateless REST paradigm and rely on identifier:

so

GET /userrecords/  --> [ { "id": 1, "data":"myrecorddata"}, ...]

GET /checkUserRecord/{id} like  /checkUserRecord/1

and yes, you will have to make two calls to the database. If your concern is performance, you can set some caching mecanism as piy26 points out, but caching could lead you to other issues (how to define a proper and reliable caching strategy ?).

Unless you manage a tremendous amount of data, I think you should first focus on providing a clear, maintainable and safely usable REST API with stateless design.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, it provides a way to enable caching on your Repository object which is what you are trying to solve.

```
@EnableCaching
org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching
```

You can use UserID as a hash attribute while creating your key so that response from different users remains unique.